# Phonegap build, plugin source has changed, but I can't get it to work

Tags: phonegap-build

I know this changed a while ago, but I've just come back to my app (as the certificate expires in a little while, so I need to rebuild). I'm having an issue rebuilding, as **PhoneGap Build** has now got rid of the plugin repo.

Before, I would use this in my *config.xml*:

```
<gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.uniquedeviceid" />
```

Now, they tell you to use **npm**. The issue with this, is that not all plugins are on there!

```
<gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.uniquedeviceid" source="npm" />
```

Gives me an error about it not being found. After some research, I came across this site:

http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/paldom/uniquedeviceid

As per their example, I've tried:

```
<gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.uniquedeviceid" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

However, I now get an error:

> plugin source unsupported: hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.uniquedeviceid
>   from plugins.cordova.io

I'm really at a loss as to how to deal with this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. You sometimes need to give the git address for a plugin, like so:

```
<gap:plugin spec="https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID.git" source="git" />
```

This has fixed my issue (still not sure why the other method didn't work though!)

Comment: Hi @andrewnewby , may I know if you are using brodysoft SQLite? Im still having an issue since yesterday and I cant make it work. Same as you our certificate is expired and I need to rebuild again my application.

Comment: @BizApps - sorry, no we are just using localStorage for our app